# How to configure postfix/dovecot setup to reject certain mail

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, filter

I followed this (https://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze/big-picture) tutorial to set up my mailserver and it works very well.

I'd like to be able to reject email from certain users or if it contains certain strings or if the title matches something.

Is this possible?

I am using MySQL for users and am in a multidomain env.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `header_checks` and  `body_checks` to block on certain strings. More info [here](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html). You can use `smtpd_sender_restrictions` to block mails from certain users. More info [here](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html).

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header.re
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/blacklisted_roles

#/etc/postfix/header.re
/^Subject:(.*) offensive_word /     REJECT Inappropriate word

#/etc/postfix/blacklisted_roles
spammer@domain.tld    REJECT
```

Comment: Sounds cool! Gotta try it. Am I able to route "rejected" mail to the receptors "spam" folder? Or does this just automatically discard everything?

Comment: The mail would be discarded and you can't able to route those messages. I would recommend to use SpamAssassin instead

Comment: @ALex_hha is right. If you want all those mails to land in Spam, Do these checks in Spamassassin Add custom headers/rewrite default Spamassassin headers and use them in your global sieve rules on dovecot side.

Comment: How do I configure spamasassin (AMaViS?) to do this?

Comment: http://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/Mail_SpamAssassin_Conf.html should help