# How to configure postfix/dovecot setup to reject certain mail for certain users/accounts

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot, filter

I'd like to be able to reject email from certain users or if it contains certain strings or if the title matches something for certain users.

I'm in a multidomain enviroment.

Is this possible? Unfortunately this ([How to configure postfix/dovecot setup to reject certain mail](https://serverfault.com/questions/579058/how-to-configure-postfix-dovecot-setup-to-reject-certain-mail)) doesn't fit my needs because it suggests to use `header_checks` and `body_checks` to block on certain strings. I could also use `smtpd_sender_restrictions` to block mails from certain users but **not** for certain users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a milter or content filter for postfix. Milter is easier especially with python and pymilter:

`https://pythonhosted.org/pymilter/examples.html`